# How to conditionally blur video using FFMPG

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I want to conditionally blur video
Like for a 30 second video form 2-10 second blur different area than 12-20 second.

But I am only able to blur it 1 time only so far,Following is the command I tried to achieve the goal.
Using [Arithematic Expressions](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation)

`ffmpeg -y -i with_out_sound.mp4
filter_complex [0:v]boxblur=10:enable='between(t,2,10)'[bg],[0:v]crop=206:169:3
2:121[fg],[bg][fg]overlay=32:121:enable='between(t,2,10)'[tmp];[0:v]boxblur=10:
enable='between(t,12,20)'[bg],[0:v]crop=206:169:42:100[fg],[bg][fg]overlay=42:100
:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tmp2];[tmp][tmp2]concat[tmp3] -map [tmp3] with_out_sou
ndd.mp4`

but above command first blur(2-10) complete video and then concat complete video again with blur (12-20) so I get 60 second video instead of 30 second.

`ffmpeg -y -i with_out_sound.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]boxblur=10:enable='between(t,2,10)'[bg];[bg]crop=206:169:32:121[fg];[bg][fg]overlay=32:121:enable='between(t,2,10)'[tmp],[tmp]b
oxblur=10:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tbg],[tmp]crop=206:169:42:100[tfg],[tbg][tfg]overlay=42:100:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tmp2] -map
 "[tmp2]" with_out_soundd.mp4`

But in this case I start receiving error
Stream specifier 'tmp' in filtergraph description matches no stream.

I am using ffmpeg latest version on windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i with_out_sound.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]boxblur=10:enable='if(between(t,2,10)+between(t,12,20),1,0)'[bg];
 [0:v]crop=206:169:32:121[fg1];[0:v]crop=206:169:42:100[fg2];
 [bg][fg1]overlay=32:121:enable='between(t,2,10)'[tmp];
 [tmp][fg2]overlay=42:100:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tmp2]"
-map [tmp2] with_blur.mp4
```

You can *add* multiple conditions to do the blur in one filter execution, and then use two overlays. The concat is avoided. If you want to use the concat, you should trim the two streams, but this is easier.

The conditional used is the `if(x,y,z)` which evaluates `x` and returns `y` if true, else `z`.

Comment: Thank you sir,For your answer,it worked perfectly,Can you tell me if this is possible to specify time for between command in milisecond instead of second,Like if(between(t,0.2,0.10)

Comment: Sure. Express it in seconds. So, 2851 milliseconds would be `2.851`

Comment: Can  you also help me to write command to blur specific area instead of the above example that blur the area out side of specified?

Comment: You have to crop the output of the blur filter and overlay that on the non-blurred background `[0:v]`.

Comment: I posted a new [question](http://superuser.com/questions/1088757/filter-boxblur-has-unconnected-output),If you have time then please consider it answering.