# Filter Boxblur has unconnected output

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I am trying to blur specific part of video depending on specific interval,like in 2-10 second blur this part and in 12-20 blur another but I am not able to get this working.
Here is the command I can make so far

```
'ffmpeg -y -i with_out_sound.mp4 -filter_complex [0:v]crop=206:169:32:121,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,2,10)'[fg];[0:v]crop=206:169:62:100,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,12,20)'[fg1];[0:v[fg]overlay=32:121:enable='between(t,2,10)'[tmp];[0:v][tmp]overlay=62:100:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tmp2]-map [tmp2] with_blur.mp4'
```

But with above command I am getting error **Filter Boxblur has unconnected output**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -y -i with_out_sound.mp4 -filter_complex \
"[0:v]crop=206:169:32:121,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,2,10)'[fg]; \
 [0:v]crop=206:169:62:100,boxblur=10:enable='between(t,12,20)'[fg1]; \
 [0:v[fg]overlay=32:121:enable='between(t,2,10)'[tmp]; \
 [tmp][fg1]overlay=62:100:enable='between(t,12,20)'[tmp2]"
-map [tmp2] with_blur.mp4
```

The result of the first overlay should be the background for the 2nd overlay.

The error was occurring because `fg1` wasn't being used anywhere. All filter outputs should be either 1)mapped for encoding, 2)used by another filter or 3) sent to a sink.